# Calculating Average after MySQL Query is Run

Tags: mysql

I've run a MySQL query (this is in wordpress php):

```
$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT Opponent, ROUND(AVG(Points),2) 
AS Avg_Points, ROUND(AVG(Plus_Minus),2) AS Avg_Plus_Minus 
FROM ' . 'afl_defense_v_position' . ' WHERE Position = "MID" 
AND Rank <= 1 AND Round >= 10 GROUP BY Opponent 
ORDER BY Avg_Plus_Minus DESC')
```

This all works fine and I can build an html table off this no problem.

What I am looking to do now though is find the standard deviation and average of the resulting `Avg_Plus_Minus` column and assign them to php variables so that I can use them to colour the table rows.

How do I assign these variables? (Once assigned I know how to code the colours)

I know how to do this by running another MySQL query and modifying the aforementioned code, however, I assume there is an easier way to calculate these from the array result of the original query.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the PECL extension `stats` and then use the `stats_standard_deviation()` function to compute the standard deviation. Also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-standard-deviation.php for a pure PHP implementation (if you do not want to install the extension).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there would any recognisable difference in total processing time for what you recommend vs just a second MySQL query added to the page?

Comment: If is always advisable to do such computations in SQL - it is specifically designed for such things. For complex statistical calculations you may need to install UDF library - e.g. https://www.xarg.org/2012/07/mysql-infusion-udf-for-statistical-analysis/

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response. I'll likely build it as extra MySQL queries then. I'm quite new to it all so wasn't sure if there was a better way to do it all.

Comment: Really appreciate the quick response